# Convert a search to a command in Vim

Tags: vimrc

Often I will do a search to find things in Vim, such as:

```
/-some-regex-here
```

And after seeing what if grabs and iterating through a few of the results, I want to do a find-replace. Is there a way to convert the `/` to a `:` command? Or do I have to `esc` and then press `:` and re-type (or copy-paste) the command again?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In command-line, you can use `ctrl-r` (see `:h c_ctrl-r`) to start inserting the content of a register.

In your case, you could paste the content of the last search with:

```
<c-r>/
```

---

Another way would be to use `:h incsearch` to show the matches as you type your search (in a `/` search, or a `:s` command, and so on), so you don't need to "check" your regex before using it in a substitute command.

Comment: that's perfect, thank you for this. I suppose it's the same if I have a command and want to paste it into a search, I could do `<c-r>:` ?

Comment: Indeed. You should definitely check `:h c_ctrl-r` ;)

Answer (score 22):

You could just do:

```
%s//REPLACEMENT/
```

From the docs:

> If the {pattern} for the substitute command is empty, the command uses the
>   pattern from the last substitute or `:global` command.  If there is none, but
>   there is a previous search pattern, that one is used.

A example can be found with `:h :s_r` and then a few lines down, beginning with "For `:s` with an argument this already happens:". The quote above is  further down in the text.

Comment: This is exactly what I do in the situation the OP describes.  I sometimes leverage an empty pattern the same way in a `:global`, too.

Answer (score 2):

Just to show another way in addition to the already existing answers:

In both the `/` and `:` command modes, you can press `ctrl-f` to essentially open the respective history as a new temporary buffer. See `:help c_ctrl-f` for details.

So, what you could to is the following:

- enter `/` `ctrl-f` (or `q/`) to open this special buffer for the search mode
- use any normal mode commands to yank the text you need
- enter the `:` command mode and insert the text, either with `ctrl-r` `"` or again using `ctrl-f`

Of course, `ctrl-r` `/` is quicker for this particular use case, but the `ctrl-f` method is more general, so maybe it's useful to someone who finds this question.

Comment: neat, but then if I'm in search, how to get the most recent `:` commands, or vice-versa?

Comment: Actually that would q/ in this case, but q: works for the command line

Comment: This is useful when one types `/%s/foo/bar` and then realizes he has mistankenly used `/` instead of `:`.